# I cannot access function through (click) directive in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app w/ Angular 2 which has a search bar, which works fine. Each time the user enters a character into the searchBar, it runs a function in the .ts file that updates the results. However, I set one of the menu buttons to initiate a different function in a (click) directive, and the console claims `TypeError: self.context.toggleAppearance is not a function`.

Here is my code:

**merit-badges.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Merit Badges</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons (click)="toggleAppearance()" end>
          <button>
              <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
          </button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-buttons end>
          <button>
              <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
          </button>
      </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let n of meritBadges">
            {{n.title}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**merit-badges.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/merit-badges/merit-badges.html',
})
export class MeritBadgesPage {

    meritBadges: Array < {
        title: string,
        type: string
    } > ;

    let searchVisible: boolean = false;

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

        this.initializeItems();

    }

getItems(ev) {
        // Reset items back to all of the items
        this.initializeItems();

        // set val to the value of the ev target
        var val = ev.target.value;

        // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
        if (val && val.trim() != '') {
            this.meritBadges = this.meritBadges.filter((meritBadge) => {
                return (meritBadge.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            });
        }
    }

    toggleAppearance(){

        console.log("APPEARANCE TOGGLED");

    }

}
```

Comment: could you solve it @mcpolo ?

Comment: @OctavioGarbarino Not with your solution, I solved it by adding 'this.toggleAppearance()' to the Constructor(). Plus, the 'end' keyword formats the button so it is displayed on the right side of the navBar.